# Should accepted answers be pinned or should answers be strictly ordered by vote?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange staff have announced a **proposal around the way answer acceptance works** - more details can be seen at [this meta SE post - unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers).

Currently, the original poster of a question can accept one non-deleted answer. This does several things,

- the question poster receives 2 rep, and the answer poster receives 15 rep
- the answer has an added green tick mark below its score and vote buttons
- *the answer itself is pinned to the top of the list of answers, regardless of sort variable*

This change will affect the last of these behaviours, **removing the pin to top**. Staff have indicated this may be configurable per site - each individual site can have this behaviour turned off or left on (with the default setting yet to be determined by consensus and research).

Please indicate by **upvoting if you agree** with the change (i.e. upvote if you *want to unpin* the accepted answer from the top) or **downvote if you disagree**. The up/downvote agree/disagree approach is [used in other meta questions and answers as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites).

To perceive how this would impact our community, worth check this query results:

[Questions with accepted answer pinned above highest scoring answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/pm/query/1463128/pm-se-questions-where-accepted-answers-dont-have-the-highest-score)

Comment: Just a note for anyone looking at the query - it only shows the difference between the most upvoted not accepted answer and the accepted answer. I noticed several of the questions have more than one answer that outscores the accepted answer.

Comment: Let's just keep the status quo that's been the same in the last 13+ years! Pin the accepted answer to the top!

Comment: Let's just change the status quo that people have been asking to change for the last 13+ years! Unpin the accepted answer from the top!